# How do I convert a hexadecimal to a string in Python?

Tags: python, hex

Using Python,

```
h = 0x11012
# ... ???
result = '11012'
```

What intermediary steps do I have to take to go from h -> result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python 2.7 and later:

```
>>> "{:x}".format(0x11012)
'11012'
```

Python 2.6:

```
>>> "{0:x}".format(0x11012)
'11012'
```

Python 2.5 and earlier:

```
>>> "%x" % 0x11012
'11012'
```

Comment: This is nicer than the somewhat arbitrary-looking `[2:]` slicing.

Comment: For older Pythons, `'%x' % 0x11012`.

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks - I've added the alternative methods

Answer (score 2):

```
h = 0x11012
result = hex(h)[2:]
```

This will remove the leading `0x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = hex(h)
```

It's really that simple.

Comment: Doesn't this have a leading `'0x'`?